# properly render an array of numeric values, not an array with strings

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, highcharts

I have this code in my symfony controller:

```
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $queryIndex = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT g.index
                                        FROM MySpaceMyBundle:Graphique g');

        $result = $queryIndex->getArrayResult();
        $arrayResult = array_map('current', $result);

        var_dump($arrayResult);

        return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:myTemplate.html.twig');
```

With my var_dump, I have this result:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => string '1700.000' (length=8)
  1 => string '1200.000' (length=8)
  2 => string '1200.000' (length=8)
  3 => string '1304.000' (length=8)
  4 => string '1800.000' (length=8)
  5 => string '2012.000' (length=8)
  6 => string '2048.000' (length=8)
  7 => string '1048.000' (length=8)
  8 => string '3000.000' (length=8)
  9 => string '5421.000' (length=8)
```

But for the obHighchartBundle (using highchart.js) the result I want is:

```
[1700,1200,1200,1304,1800,2012,2048,1048,3000,5421]
```

How can I proceed?

Note that I need to pass a numeric array (the values are decimal types in my database), not array with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arrayResult as $value) {
    $result[] = (int) $value
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: that the best soltion, even if TGA answer is a good one. I have another question for you: If my values in my array are dates (datetime) how can I proceed in my foreach loop here `$result[] = (int) $value` ? Thank you a lot for your answer.

Comment: @french_dev DateTime returns an object, I don't think you can cast it to int, instead you should fetch single values (as year, or month or day, so on.., like this `$datetimeObj->format('d')`) and use it

Comment: that's what I think about datetime. Indeed, datetime returns object. Thank you a lot for your answer, you're my hero today. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tiny tips like array_walk function to cast your values as float to prevent highchart issue. See the documentation for this function:
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php

Here an example of the tiny function :

```
<?php
function forceFloat (&$aItems) { 
   $aItems = (float) $aItems; 
}

$arrayResult = array("1.00","4.55","39494");

var_dump($arrayResult);

array_walk($arrayResult, 'forceFloat');

var_dump($arrayResult);

?>
```

The output :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1.00"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "4.55"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "39494"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  float(1)
  [1]=>
  float(4.55)
  [2]=>
  float(39494)
}
```

Best Regards,

TGA

Comment: how can I really proceed with `array_walk`? I tried `array_values ` too but when I proceed to an echo on my variable containing the array_values attr I have this message error `Notice: Array to string conversion`

Comment: I have added a complete example which work, i think that you don't need array_values

Comment: thank you for your reply. Your soltion is a good one, I try her and it works well. I just choose xurshid29 answer for refactoring my code. Thank you a lot for guiding me on this dilemma.